# Excel Interlop Error on New Server after migration

Tags: excel, vb.net, service, server

I recently migrated a windows service to a new server for my company. This service reads data from a sql table and builds an excel document from it, using a template. Unfortunately, even with all of the same code, I am getting a new error when I try to execute the service.

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC 
Stack Trace: 
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object 
UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object 
WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object 
Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object 
AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)
```

This is the code which executes leading up to the error:

```
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory() & strTemplatePath)
```

The old server is running Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2 and the new server is running Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Datacenter. Both have Excel 2003 installed.

**What I've tried:**

Prayer

Providing permissions to the user which executes the app

Setting my CurrentCulture to "en-US"

Moving the template file to c:\Templates in case of a weird issue with the program files directory

Matching the two server's settings for the "Microsoft Excel Application" within dcomcnfg and mmc-32 (neither is set to "interactive user")

Replacing the currently utilized Excel Interlop file (11.0.8161.0) with the newest version I could find (15.0.4795.1000)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

In response to comments:

Inspecting BaseDirectory and strTemplatePath yield a valid path to my excel workbook. If I paste it directly into the explorer address bar the file opens.

Comment: When debugging in Visual Studio - what does the Locals window or Immediate window show you when you inspect BaseDirectory and strTemplatePath

Comment: Change `xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass` to `xlApp = New Excel.Application` - So get rid of the word Class. Even if it works sometimes, it's not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, which turned out to be super random at the following url:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/574791/COMplusExceptionplushresultplus-x-a-ecplusatplu

All I had to do to get this to start working was create the following directory:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop